# Hopf algebras structure and quantum affine algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

I'm looking for some information about the Hopf algebras structure and the quantum groups.
In particularly I was wondering if (and eventually where) is defined in the case of quantum affine algebras of twisted type in terms of Drinfeld generators.
Thank you for any suggestion.